# Page not found error / url is not working with pk

Tags: django

I m working on learning Django with MDN project on Local Library.
My two pages are rendering whereas the book detail page is not rendering and giving error page not found. Please advice what if I have missed anything:

So far entire project is on MDN documents.

catalog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from catalog import views

app_name = 'catalog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
]
```

catalog/templates/catalog/book_detail.html

```
{% extends 'catalog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>Title: {{ book.title }}</h1>

    <p><strong>Author:</strong> <a href="{{ book.author.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.author }}</a></p>
    <p><strong>Summary:</strong> {{ book.summary }}</p>
    <p><strong>ISBN:</strong> {{ book.isbn }}</p> 
    <p><strong>Language:</strong> {{ book.language }}</p>  
    <p><strong>Genre:</strong> {{ book.genre.all|join:", " }}</p>

    <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
        <h4>Copies</h4>

    {% for copy in book.bookinstance_set.all %}
        <hr>
        <p class="{% if copy.status == 'a' %}text-success{% elif copy.status == 'd' %}text-danger{% else %}text-warning{% endif %}">{{ copy.get_status_display }}</p>
    {% if copy.status != 'a' %}<p><strong>Due to be returned:</strong> {{copy.due_back}}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><strong>Imprint:</strong> {{copy.imprint}}</p>
    <p class="text-muted"><strong>Id:</strong> {{copy.id}}</p>

    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

catalog/templates/catalog/base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'catalog/style.css' %}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    {% block title %}
    <title></title>
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            {% block sidebar %}
              <ul class="sidebar-nav list-inline1 p-2">
                <li class="list-inline-item1"><a href="{% url 'catalog:index' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item1"><a href="{% url 'catalog:books' %}">All books</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item1"><a href="">All authors</a></li>
              </ul>
            {% endblock %}
          </div>  
        </div>    
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          {% block content %}

          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, if you say 'page not found with pk', at least provide your `BookDetailView class` in views.py

Comment: Dear Mas, Please find as follows `class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book`

Comment: Not finding any problems of your urls and views if you did not change the `primary key` of `Book` model... And you say your list view works fine which means the urls is correct.. Then `/{PATH_TO_APP}/book/3/` shall work if there is a book object with pk=3

Comment: Hi Mas, I tried the above solution but its still same error. page not found 404.